# Как узнать, вернул ли данные подготовленный запрос PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Работаю с PDO и запросы, в которых есть переменные, делаю через подготовленные запросы $pdo->prepare(). Как мне узнать, что вернулось из БД после $stmt.execute()? Ведь при использовании $prepare переменная $stmt уже имеет тип PDOStatement, только без данных, а значит if (!$stmt) {} не сработает. Как узнать, что из базы данных по запросу не пришло ничего, например?
Код:

```
function auth_user($pdo, $name, $password) {

    if ( !$pdo || $name == '' || $password == '') { return false; }

    $sql                = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE name = ?";
    $stmt               = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $args               = array($name);

    $stmt->execute($args);

    if (что?) {
        // тут код для обработки случая, когда по запросу не пришло ничего
    }

}
```

Comment: так сделайте fetch,

Comment: $data = $stmt->fetchAll(); а потом count(data)

Comment: Иными словами, если запрос прошел, но не вернул ничего, то $data будет пустым массивом?

Comment: На самом деле, в данном конкретном случае отдельный код для варианта когда по запросу не пришло ничего, **не нужен**. Потому что код будет один и тот же и для случаея если пользователь не найден, и для случая если найден, но пароль не подошёл: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо получить запрошенные данные в переменную, и использовать её для проверки.

В данном случае код будет примерно такой:

```
$query = "SELECT id, password FROM users WHERE name = ?";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($args);
$response = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($response) {
    var_dump($response);
    //обрабатываем данные дальше
} else {
    echo "по данному запросу ничего не найдено";
}
```

Пример работы [https://phpize.online/](https://phpize.online/?phpses=5dfe8e7bee6f94dd847362ea8dc3d4f8&sqlses=4a869b8845c83fbbb0cc699bbae14428&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Далее ответ перебираешь циклом, примеры есть тут https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select

Comment: Если нужно проверить лишь пришло, что либо, то можно использовать fetch. Это будет быстрее.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков быстрее на  одну тысячную секунды? https://phpize.online/?phpses=f19b3f4e132f4befa91fc65e0471416a&sqlses=4a869b8845c83fbbb0cc699bbae14428&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: fetch или fetchColumn будет лучше, хоть и не намного. А передавать PDO::FETCH_ASSOC не имеет тут смысла

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков смысл тут не в проверке, а в дальнейшей обработке данных.

Comment: а может ему и не нужно дальше никак с этим работать))) А только проверить есть данные или нет

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков возможно всякое, но я предпочитаю сделать одну универсальную функцию по извлечению данных, а что там дальше, пускай контроллер разбирается с ответом этой функции.

Comment: @АлександрЧерножуков если изначально данные не нужны, то в первую очередь их и **не надо запрашивать**. То есть надо делать запрос с count() или exists(). И тогда fetchColumn() действительно будет ответом. Но если мы запрашиваем данные, и их может быть больше одной строки, то fetch()  только усложнит код

Comment: но он прав в том, что в данном конкретном случае надо использовать именно fetch(), поскольку ожидается только одна строка

Answer (score -1):

```
$resulst = $stmt->execute($args);

if ($result) { // если true, запрос отработал}
if (!$result) { // если false, запрос не отработал}
```

Comment: вопрос о том, вернул ли запрос данные

Comment: Да, это тоже часть вопроса, но как проверить, вернул ли запрос вообще хоть что-то? Что возвращает execute()? Что будет содержать $result В случае, если запрос сработал, но данных не вернул?

Comment: Для проверки на ошибки служат исключения